# unexplained error, undefined var in html

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, formula

I am starting programmer and for an assignment I was supposed to convert a formula in code.
The idea was that I would first test the formula with static variabeles which later would become dynamic in the form of sliders, with as output an alert box with the answer to the formula.
However when I compile the code the alert returns undefined.
Am I missing something specific?

Heres the code;

```
<script>


    alert(CapaciteitAanvang);
    var CapaciteitAanvang = SliderVeegbreedte *SliderVeegsnelheid * 1852 * b12() * 0.001 * SliderWindsnelheid ;

        var SliderWindsnelheid = 8;

        var SliderMobilisatie = 2;

        var SliderVaartijd = 6;

        var SliderVolume = 100;

        var SliderVeegbreedte = 100;

        var SliderVeegsnelheid = 2;

        var SliderDichtheid = 900;

        var SliderTemperatuur = 20;


        function b12(k) {
        if(D33()<=0.001)
        {k = 0;}
        else
        { k = (D33() / D29) * Math.pow(10, -3);}
        return k;
        }

        function D33(l) {       
        if((D30+D31)>= D32)
        {l = D32;}
        else
        {l = D32-(D30+D31);}
        return l;
        }

        var D29 = E95()

        function E95(j){
        if(G95<I95)
        {j = G95;}
        else
        {   if(K95>M95)
            {j = M95;}
            else
            {   if(I95<K95)
                {j = K95;}
                else
                {j = I95;}
            }
        }
        return j;
        }

        var D30 = SliderVolume * (1 / E37) * Math.log(((0.013 * E90 * 2200 * E39 * E37 * C147) / (0.082 * (E28() + 273) * SliderVolume) + 1));

        var D31 = SliderVolume * (1 - Math.exp(-7.6 * Math.pow(10, -5) * (E29()) * (C170) / Math.pow((SliderVolume - E147), 0.62) ));

        var D32 = SliderVolume;

        var G95 = 3.14 * Math.pow(1.14, 2) * Math.pow((((1025-SliderDichtheid)*9.81*SliderVolume)/1025), 0.5)*(Begintijd*3600)*Math.pow(10, -6);

        var I95 = (3.14 * Math.pow(1.45, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 2)) / (1025 * Math.pow(0.0000013, 0.5))), (1 / 3)) * Math.pow((Begintijd * 3600), 0.5)) * Math.pow(10, -6);

        var K95 = 3.14 * Math.pow(2.3, 2) * (Math.pow(((Math.pow(0.025, 2)) / (Math.pow(1025, 2) * 0.0000013)), 0.5) * Math.pow((Begintijd * 3600), 1.5) * Math.pow(10, -6));

        var M95 = Math.pow(10, 5) * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 0.75) * Math.pow(10, -6);

        var E37 = Math.pow(1158.895 * (Begintijd / SliderDichtheid - 131.5), -1.144);

        var E39 = (3.339) * Math.pow(10, 31) * Math.pow((SliderDichtheid), (-10.905));

        var C147 = 3600* 42;

        function E28(h) {
            if ((0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) +0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876) <= 0)
        {h = 0;}
        else
        { h = 0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876; }
        return h;
        }
        var E147 = SliderVolume * (1 / E37) * Math.log(((E48 * E90 * 2200 * E39 * E37 * C147) / (0.082 * (SliderTemperatuur + 273) * SliderVolume) + 1));

        var C170 = 3600 * A170;

        function E29(g) {
            if ((0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876) <= 0)
        {g = 0;}
        else
        { g = 0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876; }
        return g;
        }
        var J5 = SliderWindsnelheid;


        var E48 = 2.5 * Math.pow(10, -3) * Math.pow(SliderWindsnelheid, 0.78);

        function E90(f){
        if(G90<I90)
        {f = G90;}
        else
        {   if(K90>M90)
            {f = M90;}
        else
        {   if(I90<K90)
            {f = K90;}
            else
            {f = I90;}}}
            return f;
            }

        var G90 = 3.14 * Math.pow(1.14, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * SliderVolume) / 1025), 0.5) * C90 * Math.pow(10, -6);


        var C90 = 3600* Begintijd;

        var I90 = (3.14 * Math.pow(1.45, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 2)) / (1025 * Math.pow(0.0000013, 0.5))), (1 / 3)) * Math.pow(C90, 0.5)) * Math.pow(10, -6);

        var K90 = 3.14 * Math.pow(2.3, 2) * Math.pow(((Math.pow(0.025, 2)) / (Math.pow(1025, 2) * 0.0000013)), 0.5) * Math.pow(C90, 1.5) * Math.pow(10, -6);

        var M90 = Math.pow(10, 5) * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 0.75) * Math.pow(10, -6);

        var Begintijd = SliderMobilisatie + SliderVaartijd;

        var A170 = Begintijd;






</script>
```

Edit: just a small update I still seem to get the same error but I changed the order of variabeles and added entry parameter.

```
    var SliderWindsnelheid = 8;

    var SliderMobilisatie = 2;

    var SliderVaartijd = 6;

    var SliderVolume = 100;

    var SliderVeegbreedte = 100;

    var SliderVeegsnelheid = 2;

    var SliderDichtheid = 900;

    var SliderTemperatuur = 20;

    var Begintijd = SliderMobilisatie + SliderVaartijd;

    var J5 = SliderWindsnelheid;

    var D32 = SliderVolume;

    var A170 = Begintijd;

    var C90 = 3600 * Begintijd;

    var C170 = 3600 * A170;

    var C147 = 3600 * Begintijd;

    var E39 = (3.339) * Math.pow(10, 31) * Math.pow((SliderDichtheid), (-10.905));

    var M90 = Math.pow(10, 5) * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 0.75) * Math.pow(10, -6);

    var E37 = Math.pow(1158.895 * (Begintijd / SliderDichtheid - 131.5), -1.144);

    var M95 = Math.pow(10, 5) * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 0.75) * Math.pow(10, -6);

    var E48 = 2.5 * Math.pow(10, -3) * Math.pow(SliderWindsnelheid, 0.78);

    function E29(g) {
        if ((0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876) <= 0)
        { g = 0; }
        else
        { g = 0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876; }
        return g;
    }




    var K95 = 3.14 * Math.pow(2.3, 2) * (Math.pow(((Math.pow(0.025, 2)) / (Math.pow(1025, 2) * 0.0000013)), 0.5) * Math.pow((Begintijd * 3600), 1.5) * Math.pow(10, -6));

    var G95 = 3.14 * Math.pow(1.14, 2) * Math.pow((((1025-SliderDichtheid)*9.81*SliderVolume)/1025), 0.5)*(Begintijd*3600)*Math.pow(10, -6);

    var I95 = (3.14 * Math.pow(1.45, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 2)) / (1025 * Math.pow(0.0000013, 0.5))), (1 / 3)) * Math.pow((Begintijd * 3600), 0.5)) * Math.pow(10, -6);







    var K90 = 3.14 * Math.pow(2.3, 2) * Math.pow(((Math.pow(0.025, 2)) / (Math.pow(1025, 2) * 0.0000013)), 0.5) * Math.pow(C90, 1.5) * Math.pow(10, -6);







    function E28(h) {
        if ((0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876) <= 0)
        { h = 0; }
        else
        { h = 0.0108 * Math.pow(J5, 2) + 0.2045 * J5 - 0.2876; }
        return h;
    }


    var G90 = 3.14 * Math.pow(1.14, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * SliderVolume) / 1025), 0.5) * C90 * Math.pow(10, -6);

    var I90 = (3.14 * Math.pow(1.45, 2) * Math.pow((((1025 - SliderDichtheid) * 9.81 * Math.pow(SliderVolume, 2)) / (1025 * Math.pow(0.0000013, 0.5))), (1 / 3)) * Math.pow(C90, 0.5)) * Math.pow(10, -6);



    function E90(f) {
        if (G90 < I90)
        { f = G90; }
        else {
            if (K90 > M90)
            { f = M90; }
            else {
                if (I90 < K90)
                { f = K90; }
                else
                { f = I90; } 
            } 
        }
        return f;
    }     





    function E95(j) {
        if (G95 < I95)
        { j = G95; }
        else {
            if (K95 > M95)
            { j = M95; }
            else {
                if (I95 < K95)
                { j = K95; }
                else
                { j = I95; }
            }
        }
        return j;
    }

    var E147 = SliderVolume * (1 / E37) * Math.log(((E48 * E90 * 2200 * E39 * E37 * C147) / (0.082 * (SliderTemperatuur + 273) * SliderVolume) + 1));

    var D31 = SliderVolume * (1 - Math.exp(-7.6 * Math.pow(10, -5) * (E29(0)) * (C170) / Math.pow((SliderVolume - E147), 0.62)));

    var D29 = E95(0)

    var D30 = SliderVolume * (1 / E37) * Math.log(((0.013 * E90 * 2200 * E39 * E37 * C147) / (0.082 * (E28(0) + 273) * SliderVolume) + 1));

    function D33(l) {
        if ((D30 + D31) >= D32)
        { l = D32; }
        else
        { l = D32 - (D30 + D31); }
        return l;
    }

    function b12(k) {
        if (D33(0) <= 0.001)
        { k = 0; }
        else
        { k = (D33(0) / D29) * Math.pow(10, -3); }
        return k;
    }

    var CapaciteitAanvang = SliderVeegbreedte * SliderVeegsnelheid * 1852 * b12(0) * 0.001 * SliderWindsnelheid;
    alert(CapaciteitAanvang);
```

Many thanks from an newb in distress.

Comment: Translate this? Into what? U MAD BRO?

Comment: `alert(CapaciteitAanvang);` your alert is before the variable is defined

Comment: Huangism is spot on; switch the alert and the following line, Vaatbak.

Comment: Compile JavaScript? You mean you run the code? Anyway, you can't use variables before they have a value. This means that the `alert()` and the first `var` should be placed after all other `var`s.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, I tried it yet it still returns undefined.

Comment: Try using http://jsfiddle.net and see if you can reproduce the issue you are having

Comment: moving it to next line produces NaN, because b12() is not well defined and the multiplication fails

Comment: first define the values to start with and only AFTER that use them... also, how did you wrote so many line without testing the first ones?

Comment: Tried it in jsfiddle, thanks look like an handy site :), instead of what I got earlier I now seem to get NaN, well atleast I am making progress.

Comment: you have a lot of errors in the script ... you seem to mix the use of variables and functions, you define functions with input params but you do not call ANY of them with params... restart it and do it step by step

Comment: Is there some sort of way of seeing specificly which variable hasnt been defined? Thanks for all the help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alert` statement is **before** the assignment statement.

It will always be `undefined` before you assign a value to it.

Comment: *in JavaScript. ;) Some languages will just fail and not return `undefined` as JavaScript does. Perhaps an important distinction to make for a "starting programmer"?

Comment: because CapaciteitAanvang is not defined yet

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct that CapaciteitAanvang is defined on the next line, However just switching those will still leave you with a problem as some of the variables used to create CapaciteitAanvang are not defined until after that statement.  You need to move all of the variable definitions to the top before so they are declared before they are used.

Comment: To be exact, they all are _declared_ before use (if they weren't, the alert() would have caused an error instead of alerting `undefined`), since JS hoists variable and function declarations. However, declaring a variable does not define its value, you need an assignment to do that, i.e. you have also to initialize or define the declared variable.